# How to show options in Shopware 6 plugin?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I want to show a selectbox on my page like on the orders page, which also shows the variants in the title. How can I do this?

```
<sw-entity-single-select
  :label="$t('scg.detail.card.product.product')"
  entity="product"
  displayVariants
>
</sw-entity-single-select>
```

This is an example what i want:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see how this is done in the corresponding component: [link](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-order/component/sw-order-product-select/sw-order-product-select.html.twig#L42)

Specifically for this selection, the `sw-product-variant-info` component is used to display the variants in the select box. But of course you can fill the `result-item` slot as you like.

Comment: Also note that you have to add the association for the options and corresponding groups to the criteria of your product search request so `item.variation` will be populated: `criteria.addAssociation('options.group');`